# How to calculate the sum of specific Array Elements using vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have two arrays

```
x = [1 1 1 0 2 3 1 1]

y = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
```

How to calculate the sum of y's elements for all `x(i) = 1` to get the result `1+2+3+7+8` ?

I have used for loop and if then method to calculate the sum value like this

`if x(i) = 1  then sum = sum + y(i)`

Have other methods to get the results (sum, average, count ...) ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Since you only want to sum the numbers in y corresponding to 1s in x, but not 0s in x, you can multiply x * y which looks a bit cleaner than the If. Here are a few ways

```
Dim x = {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}
Dim y = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}

' using a for loop
Dim sum1 As Integer = 0
For i = 0 To x.Length - 1
    sum1 += If(x(i) = 1, 1, 0) * y(i)
Next
Console.WriteLine(sum1)

' using LINQ #1
Dim sum2 As Integer = x.Select(Function(i, index) If(i = 1, 1, 0) * y(index)).Sum()
Console.WriteLine(sum2)

' using LINQ #2
Dim sum3 As Integer = x.Zip(y, Function(x1, y1) If(x1 = 1, 1, 0) * y1).Sum()
Console.WriteLine(sum3)

' using LINQ #3
Dim sum4 As Integer = Enumerable.Range(0, x.Length).Sum(Function(i) If(x(i) = 1, 1, 0) * y(i))
Console.WriteLine(sum4)

Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: But if the array x's elements are not only 0 or 1 but also have others like [0 0 1 2 0 3 0 1 0] ..... How to using LINQ to select and to sum the y(i) values  for x(i)=1?  Thank you.

Comment: Maybe something other than `x = [1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1]` would have made that more clear? But I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `For` is very clear so I don't know why you wouldn't use it, but you can use LINQ for this as well:

```
Sub Main
    Dim x = {1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 1, 1}
    Dim y = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}

    Dim sum = y.Where(Function(v, i) x(i) = 1).Sum()

    Console.WriteLine("Sum is {0}", sum)
End Sub
```

Prints

> Sum is 21